# Using Special Symbols in ASP.NET MVC Routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, routes, special-characters

I want to use the url such as "/ControllerName/ActionName/Id"
Id - only digits or null.
But when I use regular expression in MapRoute, "\d{1,4}", I see the exception - error404 page, when I'm trying to see /ControllerName/ActionName/" page.

Also, I don't know, how I can catch exception with special symbol - ".
Please, help.Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `( *|\d{1,4})`.